# ElasticSearch and stunnel

Tags: elasticsearch, stunnel

I have managed to setup ElasticSearch using stunnel for single node configuration and it works fantastic. But I am having issues trying to do this for multinode zen unicast.

On server 1 I have...

**Stunnel config**

```
[es-server-native]
accept = 10.0.0.xx0:9300
connect = 127.0.0.1:9300
cert = stunnel.pem
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["what do I put here since now the nodes are not accessible externally"]
```

On server 2 I have...

**Stunnel config**

```
[es-server-native]
accept = 10.0.0.xx1:9300
connect = 127.0.0.1:9300
cert = stunnel.pem
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["what do I put here since now the nodes are not accessible externally"]
```

If I try to make the local es machine a client of itself, and start ElasticSearch I get bind address error and ElasticSearch wont start.

On Server 1

```
[es-client-native]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:9300
connect = 10.0.0.xx1:9300
```

On Server 2

```
[es-client-native]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:9300
connect = 10.0.0.xx0:9300
```

Has anyone ever used stunnel to setup ElasticSearch in cluster using unicast?